# Mouse settings missing

Tags: mouse

I am not getting any options for changing mouse sensitivity/speed, only for touchpad.

[image]

- The touchpad settings are working perfectly fine.
- I have a wireless Logitech mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only cursor speed is missing.
in terminal do :

```
xset q | grep -A 1 Pointer
```

to get the current value.
then do (example):

```
xset m 1/2 4
```

that's my current default here.
change them to your liking.
cursor theme can be changed from unity tweak tool.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
unity-tweak-tool
```